# When click on button, show divs with checked checkbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, coldfusion

I want to use JQuery on my Coldfusion application for showing/hiding div elements with checkbox checked/unchecked within the div.

Basically, in a view I show multiple divs elements, every div have also more divs inside, one of these internal divs contains an input type checkbox that could come checked or unchecked.

I also have three buttons in that view 'Active, Inactive, All'. **When clicking on Active I want to show all div elements with checkbox checked, not showing the unchecked, and the other way around when clicking on Inactive**.

```
<div class="btn-group ">
  <button id="actives" type="button">Actives</button>
  <button id="inactives" type="button">Inactives</button>
  <button id="all" type="button">All</button>
</div>

<div id="apiDiv">
  <cfloop array="#apis#" index="api">
    <div class="card card-found">
      <div class="card-header">
        <cfif Len(api.iconClass)>
          <i class="fa fa-fw #api.iconClass#"></i>
        </cfif>
        #structKeyExists( api, "name" ) ? api.name : api.id#
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>#api.description#</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-button">
        <input class="#inputClass# ace ace-switch ace-switch-3" name="#inputName#" id="#inputId#-#api.id#" type="checkbox"  value="#HtmlEditFormat( api.id )#"<cfif ListFindNoCase( value, api.id )> checked="checked"</cfif> tabindex="#getNextTabIndex()#">
        <span class="lbl"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cfloop>
</div>
```

I´m not an expert at all with JQuery. The only thing I have done is what follows and I do not know whether if is a good beggining or not:

```
$("#actives").click(function (e) {
  $("#apiDiv .card").filter(function() {
    <!--- code here --->
  });
});
```

Someone please that can help me with it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your CF code executes, it will generate a `.card` for each loop iteration of your `apis` array.  So you jQuery code will need a click handler for the `#actives` button and that will loop through `each()` iteration of the checkboxes to determine the checked/unchecked state.  At that point find the `closest()` ancestor `.card` and `show()`/`hide()` the `.card` depending upon the checkbox state.

```
$("#actives").click(function (e) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).closest(".card").show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".card").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you reply!. Your code really helps me and did the job! Much apreciated!

Comment: @PabloPortillo Glad to help.  Since my answer solved your issue, please upvote and mark as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Call the checkbox by its id and when it's checked, write a function to display the divs you want to display:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
$document.getElementById("check").onclick = function(){
    $document.getElementById("div_name").style.display="block";   // block displays the div.

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I thought about this posibility but if you take a closer look, the input checkbox id is dynamic so there is a problem there

Comment: no problem, you can use jQuery to call the button without the ID. i guess it may work out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with jQuery code:

```
$('#actives').click(function(){
        $('#apiDiv').show();
  });
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/rfkLu1c8/7/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but you are not filtering to show just the checked ones

Comment: check this edited fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/rfkLu1c8/13/

Answer (score 0):

The code you are probably looking for is in these event handlers for your buttons:

```js
function activesHandler() {
  jQuery(".card-button > input:checked").parents(".card.card-found").show();
  jQuery(".card-button > input:not(:checked)").parents(".card.card-found").hide();
}

function inactivesHandler() {
  jQuery(".card-button > input:checked").parents(".card.card-found").hide();
  jQuery(".card-button > input:not(:checked)").parents(".card.card-found").show();
}

function allHandler() {
  jQuery(".card.card-found").show();
}

jQuery("#actives").click(activesHandler);
jQuery("#inactives").click(inactivesHandler);
jQuery("#all").click(allHandler);
```

I reproduced some of your ColdFusion  by replacing it with JavaScript and provided a demonstration of the above event handlers in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kofeigen/05dcgqfx/).